# launching Safari from an app using URL stored in the array

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, url, safari

This is the a button which when clicked will open up Safari.

```
-(IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"loginClicked");

NSLog(@"currentSelectedRow = %i", currentSelectedRow );

loginObj = [appDelegate.loginArray objectAtIndex:currentSelectedRow];
NSLog(@"URL = %@", loginObj.loginURL);

Error-->[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"%@", loginObj.loginURL]];

}
```

Error: `Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 27`

If I replace `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]` with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"www.google.com"]];
```

Safari can be launched and will go to [Google](http://www.google.com) and my debugger shows the following

```
2012-01-26 16:04:15.546 Login2[197:707] loginClicked
2012-01-26 16:04:15.550 Login2[197:707] currentSelectedRow = 0
2012-01-26 16:04:15.555 Login2[197:707] URL = www.amazon.com
```

It seems that I have pulled the `URL` from my array correctly but I can't implement it to the code to open the `URL` in Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Error-->[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"%@", loginObj.loginURL]];  //Edit this line as
Correct-->[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:loginObj.loginURL]];
```

Comment: Hi Sri, thank you for your help. i tried your method and now the button is able to open up safari from the URL in my array. but the thing is the URL stored in my array is `http://www.amazon.com` but what was opened in safari is `www.amazon.com%0a/` instead and it is an invalid URL. please advice

Comment: try this. loginObj.loginURL = [[loginObj.loginURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%0a" withString:@""];[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:loginObj.loginURL]];

Comment: is there a difference if i used https instead of http? seems like when i change my URL in the array to `https://www.amazon.com` it works! but not when it is `http://www.amazon.com` i think generally your method is the best, short and sweet and the problem why it wasn't opening correctly lies with my URL in my array.

Comment: you have to use the http only.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to pass formatting parameters to

```
[NSURL URLWithString:]
```

But the URLWithString method doesn't take formatting parameters - not every method that takes a string in iOS works like `[NSSString stringWithFormat:]` or `NSLog()`.

Generally, a good clue is that a method will be named `somethingWithFormat:` instead of `somethingWithString:` if it does accept formatting parameters. You should assume that methods called `somethingWithString:` don't accept formatting arguments.

To fix you code, split it into two calls:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loginObj.loginURL];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlsString];
```

Although come to think of it, I'm not sure why you don't just write:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:loginObj.loginURL];
```

Since you aren't actually doing anything with the format string except spitting out the first argument.

Comment: Hi Nick thank you for answering my question in such detail, yes loginObj.loginURL is declared as NSString. i changed the code as per ur suggestion: `NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:loginObj.loginURL];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];` now the websites open but the URL becomes www.amazon.com%0a%/ what could be wrong? my URL in the array is `http://www.amazon.com`

Comment: Just use [NSURL URLWithString:loginObj.loginURL]; stringWithFormat treats the string as if all the %'s are placeholders for variables. Don't  use stringWithFormat unless you have parameters you want to insert into the string.